# How do I go about allowing an object of a class type to be uninitialized and identifying when this is the case without using a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I recently found out for the past few years of me using C++, I have been using pointers far too often and usually when I could easily substitute them for something more appropriate. Something I used them for was using one to allow an object to be uninitialized, and easily check so.

For example, let's say I have a camera that I want to be attaching to an object in a game:

```
Class Camera {
    public:
        Entity *attachEntity;
        Camera() {
            attachEntity = nullptr;
        }

        void update() {
            // If there's an entity to be attached to
            if (attachEntity != nullptr) {
                ...
            }
        }
};
```

Is this a bad usage of a pointer? I can't find a good way of doing this without using one. And if it's not supposed to be attached to the entity, you can just set it to `nullptr` again if it's a pointer. Otherwise, there needs to always be an `attachEntity`, despite whether or not the camera is attached to it at the moment. Is there anything wrong with this practice? Is there a good way to do this without pointers? I saw that you can't just set an object to `NULL` like you can a pointer. What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
Use [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) which auto-destructs when no longer needed.
And then you forget everything about copy/move constructors in your classes.
Also it initializes itself to `nullptr` automatically; No need for your constructor then.

You can also use std::unique_ptr if you are sure that your pointer isn't going to be duplicated, for example, when you only have one object of type `Camera`. Usually I use shared_ptr to allow copies over threads etc.

```
Class Camera {
    public:
        shared_ptr<Entity> attachEntity;

        void update() {
            // If there's an entity to be attached to
            if (attachEntity) {
                ...
            }
        }
};
```

Generally, raw pointers are only nowadays useful to call pointer-only functions, like WinAPI etc. That way, your classes won't need copy/move constructors or assignment operators or destructors, unless you want to move/dup an object which is not visible to the language, like a HANDLE in Windows.

Comment: I agree that using a raw pointer here is likely a bad idea. I don't know whether shared_ptr or unique_ptr is a better choice, though.

Comment: In case that your pointer won't be shared, you can use unique_ptr.

Answer (score 6):

1. If you want value semantics but still need to be able to omit a
   value, you can use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).
2. You get similar behavior with a [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), except that
   the Entity takes up no space when absent but otherwise goes into its
   own block of dynamically-allocated memory.
3. If you want non-owning reference to an Entity instance whose
   lifespan will exceed that of the Cameria instance, a raw pointer is
   appropriate.
4. When the Entity is potentially used by multiple Cameras (or other
   things) and you need to ensure its lifespan is extended until its
   last use, that's where [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) fits in.
5. As Michael pointed out, there's also [std::weak_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), which is
   good to know about but typically rare in practice. It's used to
   address a shared_ptr without keeping it alive.

(edited to add #5)

Comment: A raw pointer can be avoided in case 3 with the use of weak_ptr.

Comment: A weak_pointer is only appropriate (and only works) with a shared_ptr object. I'll add a case for it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to attach the camera to one specific entity and change the attachment, you need a pointer.
Since the existence of that entity should be independent of the camera, a raw pointer is appropriate.

If all your entities are shared (as `shared_ptr`s), a `weak_ptr` would be best, but it’s not obvious that they should be.

Comment: @StevenSudit `optional` doesn’t let you refer to an external, independent object unless you make it an optional pointer, so the pointer is still needed. While there are situations where you might want to distinguish between a null pointer and no pointer at all, I doubt that it would suit OP.

Comment: You're right that `optional` is a value type, so it won't let you refer to an object that is independent and potentially shared. But it's not clear to me that this is a requirement. The OP describes their goal as wanting to "allow an object to be uninitialized", which is what `optional`  is particularly good for. The lack of indirection would then becomes an advantage.

Answer (score -1):

Your solution for the camera is perfectly valid.  All the other answers take a long way around of telling you you're doing the right thing by pointing you to shared pointers and optional types, but storing the attach entity as a pointer and using it the way you are is exactly how you would expect it to be done.

I'm going to have some haters, but I personally HIGHLY encourage the use of raw pointers (instead of smart/shared pointers) for real-time applications :).

Comment: I was with you up until "... instead of smart/shared pointers for real-time applications". Those two things are not orthogonal in the slightest. Proper use of smart pointers have performance characteristics that are identical to raw pointers when it comes to dereferencing and general access -- with the only cost being on seating/destruction which can be circumvented with proper move-semantics.